# Ubuntu 18.04.3 Ethernet Issues

Tags: 18.04, internet, ethernet

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS two days ago on a PC build, but cannot get the ethernet to work. It detects the connection and says the speed is 1000mb/s, but the connection will not work.

I have an ASRock B450M Pro4 motherboard, and an AMD7 Ryzen CPU, and am not sure if this could be affecting it.

using lshw -C network

```
*-network 
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: RTL8111//8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
    logical name: enp5s0
    version: 15 
    serial: 70:85:c2:ff:c8:f8
    size: 1Gbit/s
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 
100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegation
    configuration: autonegation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full
firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
    resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcb04000-fcb04fff memory:fcb00000-fcb03fff
```

Using ip -c a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:ff:c8:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you give us more information about the issue you're facing?

Comment: @SirajusSalekin I added some more details!

Answer (score -1):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Then reboot your PC.

Comment: Tried this, it gives me ```E: Unable to locagte package r8168-dkms```

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/r8168